# VHDL: CLA subtractor Module cascade

Tags: vhdl

Good day,

I have implemented a 8 bit CLA add/subtract module and it works great. The code is below: I have strung 2 of these modules below to create a 16 bit adder/subtractor. This 16 bit version works great for addition, the carry is generated by 1 8 bit adder for the lower bits, which is then passed onto the next adder to be handled for the upper bits.

The problem is with subtraction. It doesn't work, even on paper. Let me give you an example. Lets say I want to do 350 - 50

```
300: 00000001 00101100
50:  00000000 00110010
```

Hence, if i let one adder handle the lower bits, and another handle the upper bits, it simply would not work. Here is why:

```
300:                  00000001 00101100
50 in 2's compliment: 11111111 11001110
250 is supposed to be 00000000 11111010
```

1st adder: Generates correct value after addition 11111010. That's cool. Now the second adder, is a problem. It will do (1's compliment + 1) which will give 00000000 (with carry). It was supposed to be (11111111), but because of the + 1 in the algo which is a general implementation, it screws up the final answer.

By right, since Adder 0 has no carry, Adder 1 should not do the + 1. How might I be able to implement this in the logic for the general purpose 8 bit sub/adder? Is this the correct thinking and have i covered all possible fallouts/edge cases?

```
entity CLA_ADD_SUB is
generic (N : integer := 8);
    Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N-1 downto 0);
           B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N-1 downto 0);
         Binv : in  STD_LOGIC;
         C_in: in  STD_LOGIC;
           S : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N-1 downto 0);
         TEST : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (N-1 downto 0);
           C_out : out  STD_LOGIC
           );
end CLA_ADD_SUB;

architecture CLA_ADD_SUB_ARCH of CLA_ADD_SUB is

SIGNAL    h_sum              :    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL    carry_generate     :    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL    carry_propagate    :    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL    carry_in_internal  :    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 1);

SIGNAL  B_mod : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N-1 DOWNTO 0) := B;
SIGNAL  C_in_mod: STD_LOGIC := C_in;

signal S_wider : std_logic_vector(N downto 0);


begin

    WITH Binv  SELECT
    B_mod <= B WHEN '0',
            not B WHEN '1',
            B WHEN OTHERS;

    WITH Binv  SELECT
    C_in_mod <= C_in WHEN '0',
            not C_in WHEN '1',
            C_in WHEN OTHERS;

    -- Sum, P and G
    h_sum <= A XOR B_mod;
    carry_generate <= A AND B_mod;
    carry_propagate <= A OR B_mod;

    PROCESS (carry_generate,carry_propagate,carry_in_internal,C_in_mod)
    BEGIN
        carry_in_internal(1) <= carry_generate(0) OR (carry_propagate(0) AND C_in_mod);
        inst: FOR i IN 1 TO (N-2) LOOP
            carry_in_internal(i+1) <= carry_generate(i) OR (carry_propagate(i) AND carry_in_internal(i));
        END LOOP;
        C_out <= carry_generate(N-1) OR (carry_propagate(N-1) AND carry_in_internal(N-1));
    END PROCESS;

    S(0) <= h_sum(0) XOR C_in_mod;
    S(N-1 DOWNTO 1) <= h_sum(N-1 DOWNTO 1) XOR carry_in_internal(N-1 DOWNTO 1);

end CLA_ADD_SUB_ARCH;
```

Comment: Your math snippet says `250 is supposed to be 00000000 11111010`. Below that you say the second adder outputs `00000000`. Then you say this is wrong. I don't think I understand...

Comment: Incidentally, 50 in 2's complement is `11001110`, not `11001101`.

Comment: the idea is that if we are subtracting (doing 2's compliment), we should just do a (1's compliment) if the first adder had no carry

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Your algorithm doesn't need to check to see if there was a carry (or am I missing something simple here?). The math you posted shows that just adding the 2 numbers and passing the carry works perfectly (your inputs are 300 and -50, and your result is 250). The problem seems to be where you say "It was supposed to be (11111111)" - why do you say that?

Comment: I say that because. The second adder has the Binv flag set to 1 yes, meaning it has to do a 2's compliment of the input, which is represented as above if it was all done in a 16 bit adder:

However, it is done in two stages. Hence, the first 8 bits are converted to 2's compliment by adder 0 correctly. The second adder however, will look at the straight set of 0's (for 50), and it will do a 2's compliment too (00000000 with carry 1). This is wrong, I am not supposed to do that. Only if the first stage had a carry, I do a 2's compliment in the 2nd stage, if not I do a 1's compliment

Comment: Ok, I see - from your description, it wasn't clear to me that inverting the argument was the problem. In that case, Nils's suggestion to manipulate the carry-in of the lowest-order adder seems much better than selectively inverting higher-order carries.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you did an error calculating the 2's complement of 50:

In your equation you use:

```
50 in 2's compliment: 11111111 11001101   <--- WRONG.
```

which is just 50 with all bits inverted. two's complement however is build by first inverting the bits, then add one to it.

The correct representation of -50 in 16 bit integers is:

```
50 in 2's compliment: 11111111 11001110
```

If we now do the math of 300 - 50 we'll get:

```
  00000001 00101100   | 300
+ 11111111 11001110   | -50 in 2's complement form
-------------------
  00000000 11111010   | 250 (expected result)
```

For your VHDL implementation that means that you can implement subtraction by re-using the addition part. To do so build the two's complement in two steps:

If subtraction-mode:

- negate all bits of B prior to addition
- force the carry-in of the low 8 bit adder to high.

The second step will add the one to the negated B which then is a correct two's complement number. Now you add your numbers as usual and get a functional subtracter.

Comment: Ah I get it, actually what I did was for all subsequent adders (for bits 7-15 etc.) I set the Carry for those to (Binv xor Adder_0_Carry). Hence, if the 1st adder has a carry due to the + 1 for the 2's compliment, it will propogate out of the carry, and since I xor it with Binv, I tell the second adder to not add a carry.

Comment: Also, yeah i did mess up the 50 my bad. i should edit the question

Comment: Have you tried your code with the changes already? The fix should be easy to do.

Comment: yes, it seems to work now. have posted my answer below, let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

```
u_ADDER_0: entity work.CLA_ADD_SUB(CLA_ADD_SUB_ARCH)
    port map(
           A => ADDER_0_A, -- Bits 0-7
           B => ADDER_0_B,
         Binv => TOADD_BINV,
         C_in => ADDER_0_CARRY_IN,
           S => ADDER_0_SUM,
         TEST => ADDER_0_TEST,
           C_out => ADDER_0_CARRY_OUT
    );

u_ADDER_1: entity work.CLA_ADD_SUB(CLA_ADD_SUB_ARCH)
    port map(
           A => ADDER_1_A, --Bits 7 to 15
           B => ADDER_1_B,
         Binv => TOADD_BINV,
         C_in => TOADD_BINV xor ADDER_0_CARRY_OUT,
           S => ADDER_1_SUM,
         TEST => ADDER_1_TEST,
           C_out => ADDER_1_CARRY_OUT
    );
```

Ah I get it, actually what I did was for all subsequent adders (for bits 7-15 etc.) I set the Carry for those to (Binv xor Adder_0_Carry). Hence, if the 1st adder has a carry due to the + 1 for the 2's compliment, it will propogate out of the carry, and since I xor it with Binv, I tell the second adder to not add a carry.

**the idea is that if we are subtracting (doing 2's compliment), we should just do a (1's compliment) if the first adder had no carry**

I cannot confirm this for all test cases. This is just a theory and so far it seems to work

Comment: Hmm..if I set B_inv to 0, meaning I am doing addition, and I pass in two signed bits. say 50 and -250, it won't work, because the second adder's C_in is determined by Binv xor Adder_0_carry.

Answer (score 0):

This is supplemental to your own answer.

**Hmm..if I set B_inv to 0, meaning I am doing addition, and I pass in two signed bits. say 50 and -250, it won't work, because the second adder's C_in is determined by Binv xor Adder_0_carry**

I think your manual arithmetic is faulty:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity tb_add_sub_gang is
    constant n:    natural := 8;
end entity;

architecture foo of tb_add_sub_gang is
    signal a:       std_logic_vector (2*n-1 downto 0);
    signal b:       std_logic_vector (2*n-1 downto 0);
    signal s:       std_logic_vector (2*n-1 downto 0);
    signal test:    std_logic_vector (2*n-1 downto 0);
    signal binv:    std_logic;
    signal cout0:   std_logic;
    signal cin1:    std_logic;
    signal cout1:   std_logic;

begin

    cin1 <= cout0 xor binv;

uadder0: 
    entity work.cla_add_sub(cla_add_sub_arch)
        port map(
            a => a((2*n-1)/2 downto 0), -- bits 0-7
            b => b((2*n-1)/2 downto 0),
            binv => binv,
            c_in => '0',
            s => s((2*n-1)/2 downto 0),
            test => s((2*n-1)/2 downto 0),
            c_out => cout0
        );

uadder1: 
    entity work.cla_add_sub(cla_add_sub_arch)
        port map(
            a => a(2*n-1 downto n), --bits 8 to 15
            b => b(2*n-1 downto n),
            binv => binv,
            c_in => cin1,
            s => s(2*n-1 downto n),
            test => test(2*n-1 downto n),
            c_out => cout1
        );
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 100 ns;
        a <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(350,a'length));
        b <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(50,b'length));
        binv <= '1';
        wait for 100 ns;
        binv <= '0';
        wait for 100 ns;
        a <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(50,a'length));
        b <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(250,b'length));
        binv <= '1';
        wait for 100 ns;
        binv <= '0';
        wait for 600 ns;
        wait;
    end process;    
end architecture;
```

Gives:

[image: tb_add_sub_ganged.png]

(I update the waveform image for your signed subtraction/addition).

The binv selector in `cla_add_sub` is the equivalent of XOR between `Binv` and `C_in`.  XORing `Binv` in again externally for the Most Significant `n` bit adder is gives you an even number number of XORs removing their effect, carrying in the carry out of the Least Significant adder.

The proper thing to do is actually to only invert `B` with `Binv` and use `Binv` to also invert the carry in of the LS adder.  Because you never carry in to it other than for subtraction, hook it directly to `Binv`.  This will fix everything.

in `cla_add_sub` comment out:

```
-- WITH Binv  SELECT
-- C_in_mod <= C_in WHEN '0',
--         not C_in WHEN '1',
--         C_in WHEN OTHERS;
```

The declaration for `C_in_mod`:

```
-- SIGNAL  C_in_mod: STD_LOGIC := C_in;
```

And use `C_in` directly:

```
PROCESS (carry_generate,carry_propagate,carry_in_internal,C_in)
BEGIN
    carry_in_internal(1) <= carry_generate(0) OR (carry_propagate(0) AND C_in);
    inst: FOR i IN 1 TO (N-2) LOOP
        carry_in_internal(i+1) <= carry_generate(i) OR (carry_propagate(i) AND carry_in_internal(i));
    END LOOP;
    C_out <= carry_generate(N-1) OR (carry_propagate(N-1) AND carry_in_internal(N-1));
END PROCESS;
```

And for `S(0)`:

```
S(0) <= h_sum(0) XOR C_in;
```

In the top level:

```
-- signal cin1:    std_logic;
-- cin1 <= cout0 xor binv;

uadder0: 
    entity work.cla_add_sub(cla_add_sub_arch)
        port map(
            a => a((2*n-1)/2 downto 0), -- bits 0-7
            b => b((2*n-1)/2 downto 0),
            binv => binv,
            c_in => binv,
            s => s((2*n-1)/2 downto 0),
            test => s((2*n-1)/2 downto 0),
            c_out => cout0
        );

uadder1: 
    entity work.cla_add_sub(cla_add_sub_arch)
        port map(
            a => a(2*n-1 downto n), --bits 8 to 15
            b => b(2*n-1 downto n),
            binv => binv,
            c_in => cout,
            s => s(2*n-1 downto n),
            test => test(2*n-1 downto n),
            c_out => cout1
        );
```

And that gives the same results as shown above.

And notice this is in keeping with Nils answer.

If you only had an `n` bit adder/subtractor you'd use the method in your answer where carry out (LS) to carry in (MS) would be inverted again to chain two 8 bit operations together.

This instantiates two adders that happen to invert `B`, the 1's complement part of 2's Complement to subtract 'B'.  You could add an input to `cla_add_sub` signify when it's the LS adder and only XOR `Binv` then.  That way it could serve as either a stand alone `n` bit adder or one that can be daisy chained.